# sessionFactory returns null

Tags: session, grails, grails-orm

I am trying to do batch insert with GORM and I try to clear session after every 50 insert. and I try this for get sessionFactory

```
def sessionFactory
```

but when I try to use `sessionFactory.currentSession` it returns `Null Pointer Exception` because `sessionFactory` is null. Do u know why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i believe [Burt's reply](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/How-does-injection-works-exactly-sessionFactory-not-injected-correctly-tp1353300p1353303.html) on a similar question will help you with this.

by the way, you can subscribe to [grails turkey](http://groups.google.com/group/grails-turkiye) group :)